# AttributeError: encode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the below error when I pass pretty table

```
    msg = MIMEText(self.body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/message.py", line 224, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/message.py", line 266, in set_charset
    cte(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/encoders.py", line 73, in encode_7or8bit
    orig.encode('ascii')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/prettytable.py", line 217, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: encode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly convert your table to a `unicode` string object first before adding it to your email:

```
yourtable = unicode(yourtable)
```

Comment: @user3435964: `MimeText()` can only handle `unicode` or `str` values; a PrettyTable is neither. It supports conversion, which is what using `str.format()` or `print` or what have you all will make use of. But for `MimeText()` you simply need to do the conversion explicitly.

Comment: @user3435964: glad you found both answers helpful; you can only mark **one** as accepted however. :-) You now marked Daniel's as helpful again, after switching between the two of us several times before.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters: I am not aware of that I can mark only one as Accepted.. To be honest your answer served my purpose. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe even use:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
msg = MIMEText(force_text(self.body))
```

But take care since it seems self.body is not a string...?